# Select2 em vários campos com mesmo nome

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery-select2

Estou fazendo uma pagina de cadastro de pedidos, onde pode-se cadastrar vários produtos.

Para cadastrar os produtos os usuários tem as opções de `Produto, quantidade, valor, subtotal`, caso queiram adicionar mais um produto, tem uma função que adiciona mais uma linha destes campos. 
[image: campos do produto]

O meu problema é que eu estou usando o ***Select2*** para buscar os produtos no banco de dados, porém, o ***Select2*** só funciona no primeiro campo de produto, se eu adicionar mais 1 produto, ele não funciona o ***Select2***.

[image: múltiplos produtos]

Podem notar que os campos de produto possuem diferença, pois um esta com o ***Select2*** e outro não.

O código **JS** que estou usando para essa busca é esse:

```
$( "#produto" ).select2({        
    ajax: {
        url: "modulos/orcamentos_funcao.php?buscar=produto",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

Resumindo, preciso de uma busca dinâmica para os produtos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tive um problema similar há muito tempo atrás. Na época, desisti de procurar, mas acredito que com o recurso "on" do jQuery você consiga reiniciar o select2 para elements adicionados dinamicamente.

Tenta adicionar o select2 "manualmente" dentro do clone do seu elemento.

Comment: pode dar 1 exemplo por favor?

Answer (score 1):

Tive um problema igual a esse e encontrei uma solução funcional que quando você adicionar um novo item na lista que é quando buga o Select2, você "destroy" o Select2 e inicia novamente.

```
// inicia componente select
    $(".arrCentroCusto").select2({
        tags: true
    });

$(".adicionarCampo").click(function () { // clona a linha do select
        $('.arrCentroCusto').select2("destroy"); // destroi o select2 para não bugar
        novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone(); // clona a linha
        novoCampo.find("input").val(""); // tras a nova linha como null
        novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last"); //bota a nova linha em baixo
        removeCampo(); 

        $('.arrCentroCusto').select2();//inicia o select2 novamente
    });
```